# D&D Manual Copyright

Tags: copyright

I'm working on a program for D&D enthusiasts that helps dungeon masters keep track of their characters and streamline battles. I want to transcribe the all the monster data in the Monster Manual so my program can automatically deal damage and so players could look up monster data within the program itself. Would that be violating copyright law if I did that?

Edit 1: To clarify, I'm not planning on making any money off of this(Ad revenue or otherwise).

Comment: Can you confirm the edition of dnd? The licenses are different.

Comment: I'm gonna use 5e since that's the most up to date as far as I know.

Comment: Do you plan to derive income from it in any way?  For example, if you're not going to sell the software but you do plan to host it on a server and charge users for access, that's still a commercial use.  (For what it's worth: whether the use is commercial or not may be irrelevant.)

Comment: Advertisement revenue would also be commercial

Comment: I was planning on just putting it out on github or something for everyone and having the libraries be a few text files

Comment: So you're going to take commercial material and repost it openly online without the permission of the owner, and you have to ask whether that would breach copyright?

Answer (score 6):

### Let’s work it through

> Is the work copyright?

Yes.

> Are you making a copy or a derivative work?

Yes.

> Do you have permission?

No.

At this point, it is *prima facie* copyright violation. However, various copyright laws have defences for breach. You don’t say where you are but as the USA is the most permissive in this regard we’ll use the USA. If it’s not legal there, it’s not legal anywhere. If it is legal there, it’s still likely to be not legal everywhere else.

> is it [fair use](https://copyright.gov/fair-use/more-info.html)?

Almost certainly not.

Wizards of the Coast (the copyright owner) already do this. While this service is free for creatures from the Monster Manual, it does drive traffic to their web site where they sell stuff. They also licence (presumably for money) others to do the same. Your usage would negatively affect the copyright owners market. This counts against fair use.

Because it’s already being done, your work has virtually nil transformative value. This counts against fair use.

You are copying a substantial part of the work. This counts against fair use.

You are not using it commercially but neither is it for educational use. This is unlikely to matter.

On balance: not fair use.

### TL;DR

This is copyright violation.